# A* algorithm to find the shortest path

Tags: json, python-3.x

In a JSON file I write myself, I keep hueristic and real distances between cities. Then I try to find the shortest path between ANKARA and GAZIANTEP with the A * algorithm by pulling the data from this JSON file. But the code I wrote always stays there after the next closest city from ANKARA.

That's why the while loop, the endless loop.

My Code:

```
import json as JS
import operator

def main():
    with open('provinces.json', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        tree = JS.load(f)

    path = []
    Astar(tree, path)

def Astar(tree, path):

    province_of_cost = {}
    counter = 0
    visited_cost = 0
    goal_province = ''

    while goal_province != 'Gaziantep':
        for province in tree['children']:
            cost = 0
            cost = visited_cost + province['heuristic'] + province['distance']
            province_of_cost[cost] = tree['children'][counter]
            counter = counter + 1

        counter = 0
        sorted_costs = sorted(province_of_cost.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
        path.append(tree['name'])
        tree = sorted_costs[0][1]

        visited_cost = visited_cost + tree['distance']
        goal_province = tree['name']

    print(path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output I want:

Ankara -> Kırıkkale -> Kırşehir -> Nevşehir -> Kayseri -> Kahramanmaraş -> Gaziantep

The output of this code:

Ankara -> Kırıkkale -> Kırıkkale ->Kırıkkale -> ...